# QuickCheck giving up investigating a recursive data structure (rose tree.)

Tags: haskell, recursion, quickcheck

Given an arbitrary tree, I can construct a subtype relation over that tree, using Schubert numbering:

```
constructH :: Tree a -> Tree (Type a)
```

where `Type` nests the original label, and additionally provides the data needed to perform child/parent (or subtype) checks. With Schubert Numbering, the two Int parameters are sufficient for that.

```
data Type a where !Int -> !Int -> a -> Type a
```

This leads to the binary predicate

```
subtypeOf :: Type a -> Type a -> Bool
```

I now want to test with QuickCheck that this does indeed do what I want it to do. The following property, however, does not work, because QuickCheck just gives up:

```
subtypeSanity ∷ Tree (Type ()) → Gen Prop
subtypeSanity Node { rootLabel = t, subForest = f } =
  let subtypes = concatMap flatten f
  in (not $ null subtypes) ==> conjoin
     (forAll (elements subtypes) (\x → x `subtypeOf` t):(map subtypeSanity f))
```

If I leave out the recursive call to `subtypeSanity`, i.e. the tail of the list I'm passing to `conjoin`, the property runs fine, but tests just the root node of the tree! How can I descend into my data structure recursively without QuickCheck giving up on generating new test cases?

If needed, I could provide the code to construct the Schubert Hierarchy, and the `Arbitrary` instance for `Tree (Type a)`, to provide a complete runnable example, but that would be quite a bit of code. I'm convinced that I'm just not "getting" QuickCheck, and using it in the wrong way here.

EDIT: unfortunately, the `sized` function does not seem to eliminate the problem here. It ends up with the same result (see comment to J. Abrahamson's answer.)

EDIT II: I ended up "fixing" my problem by avoiding the recursive step, and avoiding `conjoin`. We just make a list of all nodes in the tree, then test the single-node property (which worked fine from the beginning) on those.

```
allNodes ∷ Tree a → [Tree a]
allNodes n@(Node { subForest = f }) = n:(concatMap allNodes f)

subtypeSanity ∷ Tree (Type ()) → Gen Prop
subtypeSanity tree = forAll (elements $ allNodes tree)
  (\(Node { rootLabel = t, subForest = f }) →
    let subtypes = concatMap flatten f
    in (not $ null subtypes) ==> forAll (elements subtypes) (\x → x `subtypeOf` t))
```

Tweaking the `Arbitrary` instance for trees did not work. Here is the arbitrary instance I'm still using:

```
instance (Arbitrary a, Eq a) ⇒ Arbitrary (Tree (Type a)) where
  arbitrary = liftM (constructH) $ sized arbTree

arbTree ∷ Arbitrary a ⇒ Int → Gen (Tree a)
arbTree n = do
  m ← choose (0,n)
  if m == 0
    then Node <$> arbitrary <*> (return [])
    else do part ← randomPartition n m
            Node <$> arbitrary <*> mapM arbTree part

-- this is a crude way to find a sufficiently random x1,..,xm,
-- such that x1 + .. + xm = n, for any n, m, with 0 < m.
randomPartition ∷ Int → Int → Gen [Int]
randomPartition n m' = do
  let m = m' - 1
  seed ← liftM ((++[n]) . sort) $ replicateM m (choose (0,n))
  return $ zipWith (-) seed (0:seed)
```

I consider the problem "solved for now," but if someone could explain to me why the recursive step and/or `conjoin` made QuickCheck give up (after passing "only" 0 tests,) I would be more than grateful.

Answer (score 7):

When generating `Arbitrary` recursive structures, QuickCheck is often a bit too eager and generates sprawling, enormous random examples. These are undesirable as they usually don't better check the properties of interest and can be very slow. Two solutions are

1. Use things like the size parameter (`sized` function) and `frequency` function to bias the generator toward small trees.
2. Use a small-type oriented generator like those in `smallcheck`. These try to exhaustively generate all "small" examples and thus help to keep the size of the tree down.

To clarify the `sized` and `frequency` method of controlling generation size, here's an example `RoseTree`

```
data Rose a = It a | Rose [Rose a]

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Rose a) where
  arbitrary = frequency 
    [ (3, It <$> arbitrary)                   -- The 3-to-1 ratio is chosen, ah,
                                              -- arbitrarily...
                                              -- you'll want to tune it
    , (1, Rose <$> children)
    ]
    where children = sized $ \n -> vectorOf n arbitrary
```

It can be done even more simply with a different `Rose` formation by very carefully controlling the size of the child list

```
data Rose a = Rose a [Rose a]

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Rose a) where
  arbitrary = Rose <$> arbitrary <*> sized (\n -> vectorOf (tuneUp n) arbitrary)
    where tuneUp n = round $ fromIntegral n / 4.0
```

You could do this without referencing `sized`, but that gives the user of your `Arbitrary` instance a knob to ask for larger trees if needed.

Comment: yes, smallcheck. although they use "depth" (of tree) where they should IMHO use "size" (number of nodes), to avoid or at least postone a similar blow-up in the number of examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the sized function doesn't help me here at all: `quickCheck (resize 1 $ property subtypeSanity)` also gives up! I could switch to small-check, but that would mean rewriting a lot of test code. I find it a bit hard to believe that QuickCheck isn't suited to this type of testing. Is this a bug, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I'll add a demonstration of the technique I'm suggesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion didn't work for me. I might add that my `Arbitrary` instance for rose trees (and indeed subtype hierarchies) did not generate unreasonably large examples, but reacted well to the sized parameter. I did, however circumvent the problem. I'll edit my post, since it is not really an answer to the original question, just a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

In case it's useful for those stumbling across this issue: when QuickCheck "gives up", it's a sign that your pre-condition (using `==>`) is too hard to satisfy.

QuickCheck uses a simple rejection sampling technique: pre-conditions have *no* effect on the generation of values. QuickCheck generates a bunch of random values like normal. *After* these are generated, they're sent through the pre-condition: if the result is `True`, the property is tested with that value; if it's `False`, that value is discarded. If your pre-condition rejects most of the values QuickCheck has generated, then QuickCheck will "give up" (better to give up completely, than to make statistically dubious pass/fail claims).

In particular, QuickCheck will *not* attempt to produce values which satisfy a given pre-condition. It's up to you to make sure that the generator you're using (`arbitrary` or otherwise) produces lots of values which pass your pre-condition.

Let's see how this is manifesting in your example:

```
subtypeSanity :: Tree (Type ()) -> Gen Prop
subtypeSanity Node { rootLabel = t, subForest = f } =
  let subtypes = concatMap flatten f
  in (not $ null subtypes) ==> conjoin
     (forAll (elements subtypes) (`subtypeOf` t):(map subtypeSanity f))
```

There is only one occurance of `==>`, so its precondition (`not $ null subtypes`) must be too hard to satisfy. This is due to the recursive call `map subtypeSanity f`: not only are you rejecting any `Tree` which has an empty `subForest`, you're *also* (due to the recursion) rejecting any `Tree` where the `subForest` contains `Tree`s with empty `subForest`s, *and* rejecting any `Tree` where the `subForest` contains `Tree`s with `subForest`s containing `Tree`s with empty `subForest`s, and so on.

According to your `arbitrary` instance, `Tree`s are only nested to finite depth: eventually we will always reach an empty `subForest`, hence your recursive precondition will always fail, and QuickCheck will give up.